# How to increment the old array list key 5 times dynamically when I press the button using React Js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have problem where I need to increment the key object. let say my last key is 5 I want to increment it 5 times the result will be 6, 7, 8, 9, 10. Right now I when I press the button only the 10th index is set to the state the 6, 7, 8, 9 index is not showing.

Default State 5 Row:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([{
    key: "1",
    customer: <select className="form-control" name="customer1" >
                    <option value="" key="0" disabled selected>Select Customer</option>
                    <option value="" key="1">LEXI INC / joseph</option>
                    <option value="" key="1">LEXI INC / james</option>
                    <option value="" key="1">LEXI INC / charlie</option>
                    <option value="" key="1">LEXI INC / pam</option>
                    <option value="" key="1">LEXI INC / regorio</option>
                </select>,
    bank: <select className="form-control" name="bank1">
                <option value="" key="0" disabled selected>Select Bank</option>
                <option value="" key="1">BDO</option>
                <option value="" key="1">MAY BANK</option>
                <option value="" key="1">EAST WEST BANK</option>
                <option value="" key="1">UNION BANK</option>
                <option value="" key="1">BPI</option>
            </select>,
    branch: <input className="form-control" placeholder="Branch" name="branch1"/>,
    check_no: <input type="number" className="form-control" name="checkNo1" placeholder="Check No."/>,
    date: <input type="date" name="checkDate1" className="form-control"/>,
    amount: <input
                name="amount1"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Amount" 
            />,
    remarks: <select className="form-control" name="remarks1">
                <option value="" key="0" disabled selected>Select Remarks</option>
                <option value="" key="1">Test</option>
            </select>,
    
},
{
    key: "2",
    customer: <select className="form-control" name="customer2" >
                <option value="" key="0" disabled selected>Select Customer</option>
                <option value="" key="1">LEXI INC / james</option>
                <option value="" key="1">LEXI INC / charlie</option>
                <option value="" key="1">LEXI INC / pam</option>
                <option value="" key="1">LEXI INC / regorio</option>
            </select>,
    bank: <select className="form-control" name="bank2">
            <option value="" key="0" disabled selected>Select Bank</option>
            <option value="" key="1">BDO</option>
            <option value="" key="1">MAY BANK</option>
            <option value="" key="1">EAST WEST BANK</option>
            <option value="" key="1">UNION BANK</option>
            <option value="" key="1">BPI</option>
        </select>,
    branch: <input className="form-control" placeholder="Branch" name="branch2"/>,
    check_no: <input type="number" className="form-control" name="checkNo2" placeholder="Check No."/>,
    date: <input type="date" name="checkDate2" className="form-control"/>,
    amount: <input
            name="amount2"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Amount" 
            />,
    remarks: <select className="form-control" name="remarks2">
                <option value="" key="0" disabled selected>Select Remarks</option>
                <option value="" key="1">Test</option>
            </select>,
},
{
    key: "3",
    customer: <select className="form-control" name="customer3" >
                <option value="" key="0" disabled selected>Select Customer</option>
                <option value="" key="1">LEXI INC / james</option>
                <option value="" key="1">LEXI INC / charlie</option>
                <option value="" key="1">LEXI INC / pam</option>
                <option value="" key="1">LEXI INC / regorio</option>
            </select>,
    bank: <select className="form-control" name="bank3">
            <option value="" key="0" disabled selected>Select Bank</option>
            <option value="" key="1">BDO</option>
            <option value="" key="1">MAY BANK</option>
            <option value="" key="1">EAST WEST BANK</option>
            <option value="" key="1">UNION BANK</option>
            <option value="" key="1">BPI</option>
        </select>,
    branch: <input className="form-control" placeholder="Branch" name="branch3"/>,
    check_no: <input type="number" className="form-control" name="checkNo3" placeholder="Check No."/>,
    date: <input type="date" name="checkDate3" className="form-control"/>,
    amount: <input
            name="amount3"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Amount" 
            />,
    remarks: <select className="form-control" name="remarks3">
                <option value="" key="0" disabled selected>Select Remarks</option>
                <option value="" key="1">Test</option>
            </select>,
},
{
    key: "4",
    customer: <select className="form-control" name="customer4" >
                <option value="" key="0" disabled selected>Select Customer</option>
                <option value="" key="1">LEXI INC / james</option>
                <option value="" key="1">LEXI INC / charlie</option>
                <option value="" key="1">LEXI INC / pam</option>
                <option value="" key="1">LEXI INC / regorio</option>
            </select>,
    bank: <select className="form-control" name="bank4">
            <option value="" key="0" disabled selected>Select Bank</option>
            <option value="" key="1">BDO</option>
            <option value="" key="1">MAY BANK</option>
            <option value="" key="1">EAST WEST BANK</option>
            <option value="" key="1">UNION BANK</option>
            <option value="" key="1">BPI</option>
        </select>,
    branch: <input className="form-control" placeholder="Branch" name="branch4"/>,
    check_no: <input type="number" className="form-control" name="checkNo4" placeholder="Check No."/>,
    date: <input type="date" name="checkDate4" className="form-control"/>,
    amount: <input
            name="amount4"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Amount" 
            />,
    remarks: <select className="form-control" name="remarks4">
                <option value="" key="0" disabled selected>Select Remarks</option>
                <option value="" key="1">Test</option>
            </select>,
},
{
    key: "5",
    customer: <select className="form-control" name="customer5" >
                <option value="" key="0" disabled selected>Select Customer</option>
                <option value="" key="1">LEXI INC / james</option>
                <option value="" key="1">LEXI INC / charlie</option>
                <option value="" key="1">LEXI INC / pam</option>
                <option value="" key="1">LEXI INC / regorio</option>
            </select>,
    bank: <select className="form-control" name="bank5">
            <option value="" key="0" disabled selected>Select Bank</option>
            <option value="" key="1">BDO</option>
            <option value="" key="1">MAY BANK</option>
            <option value="" key="1">EAST WEST BANK</option>
            <option value="" key="1">UNION BANK</option>
            <option value="" key="1">BPI</option>
        </select>,
    branch: <input className="form-control" placeholder="Branch5" name="branch5"/>,
    check_no: <input type="number" className="form-control" name="checkNo5" placeholder="Check No."/>,
    date: <input type="date" name="checkDate5" className="form-control"/>,
    amount: <input
            name="amount5"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Amount" 
            />,
    remarks: <select className="form-control" name="remarks5">
                <option value="" key="0" disabled selected>Select Remarks</option>
                <option value="" key="1">Test</option>
            </select>,
}])
```

Add Rows Function:

```
const addRows = () => {

    //loop here the keys listed

  


    let newArr=[...data(5)].map((_,i)=>{
        let val=i+6;
         return {
            key: val,
            customer: <select className="form-control" name="customer6" >
                            <option value="" key="0" disabled selected>Select Customer</option>
                            <option value="" key="6">LEXI INC / joseph</option>
                            <option value="" key="6">LEXI INC / james</option>
                            <option value="" key="6">LEXI INC / charlie</option>
                            <option value="" key="6">LEXI INC / pam</option>
                            <option value="" key="6">LEXI INC / regorio</option>
                        </select>,
            bank: <select className="form-control" name="bank6">
                        <option value="" key="0" disabled selected>Select Bank</option>
                        <option value="" key="6">BDO</option>
                        <option value="" key="6">MAY BANK</option>
                        <option value="" key="6">EAST WEST BANK</option>
                        <option value="" key="6">UNION BANK</option>
                        <option value="" key="6">BPI</option>
                    </select>,
            branch: <input className="form-control" placeholder="Branch" name="branch6"/>,
            check_no: <input type="number" className="form-control" name="checkNo6" placeholder="Check No."/>,
            date: <input type="date" name="checkDate1" className="form-control"/>,
            amount: <input
                        name="amount6"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Amount" 
                    />,
            remarks: <select className="form-control" name="remarks6">
                        <option value="" key="0" disabled selected>Select Remarks</option>
                        <option value="" key="6">Test</option>
                    </select>
         }
    })

    setData([...data,...newArr])


    

  

}
```

My Current Output:

[image: My Current Output]

Expected Output:
When the last index is 5, then when I click the button it will turn to 10. Then now when its already 10. when I press again the button it will turn to 15 rows.

Error:

[image: error]

[image: Current Output]

Answer (score 1):

Try to create an empty array of 5 items then map it to return a new that contains the new objects :

```
const addRows = () => {

    let initialKey = 0;
    
    const x = data.slice(-1);
    
    initialKey = parseInt(x[0]['key']);

    console.log(initialKey);

/*********/
 let newArr=[...Array(5)].map((_,i)=>{
             let val=data.length+i+1;
              return {
                 key: val,
                 customer: <select >... </select>,
                bank: <select ...,
                amount: <input .../>,
                remarks: <select .... </select>,
        }
 })//map end

  setData([...data,...newArr])

/**********/
}
```

Comment: data is not a function or its return value is not iterable it shows error

Comment: please explain more the new issue

Comment: sorry, Can I ask what is ...Array(5) use for?

Comment: `[...Array(5)]` gives you an array of undefined items like `[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]`

Comment: based on your given example, i create fake 5 array with null value. now after I try your suggestion it says fake_array is not a function or its return value is not iterable

Comment: please show me the new code, paste it here https://pastebin.com/ and give me the link

Comment: it should be `Array` in `=[...data(5)]` which is a reserved keyword that create new array

Comment: with `let newArr=[...Array(5)].map((_,i)=>{` should work, please show me a screenshot of the error

Comment: I already update my content please refresh your page

Comment: but you're still using `data` , you should use `Array` instead of `data`

Comment: Hi yes your correct now, but the logic of incrementing the index is wrong. please see the image.

Comment: try with `let val=data.length+i+1;`

Answer (score 0):

The `useState` hook is asynchronous so the state is not updated exactly at the end of each `for` loop. Each loop is executed with the same value of `data`, the value you had when calling the function `addRows`. You must add the five rows at once in a single call of `setData(...)`.